# How to crypt and share a directory on OS-X via NFS?

Tags: mac, encryption, file-sharing, nfs

We have an osx desktop Environment with nfs shares and using linux/vm´s as nfs-clients
We want to encrpyt the nfs-data/directories on our os-x machines.

Is that possible? Apple´s File-Fault is using kerberos, but file-fault data isnt´ accessible via nfs. Is there a possibility to use file-vault anyway or should we use truecrypt volumes?

How do we setup truecypt/filevault + nfs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is only one scenario that I can think of where encrypting data on an NSF server makes sense, and that is to protect your data if someone steals the server.  The reason is that the filesystem must be unencrypted for the NFS server to work.  The only way around this would be if the NSF server itself decrypts data on demand.  You would also need to ensure the security of the data over the wire and on the clients.

For the case where it makes sense, put the data on an encrypted disk image created using *Disk Utility*.  Mount the disk when the server boots and startup NSF.

Comment: this is exactly the intention: protection against stealing the harddisks.

I figured out, that FileVault prevents other users, like the build in apache, but not our nfs server settings.
This is because, the nfs is activated by a deamon wich runs is started right after a specific userlogin.